# FTP not letting me upload files

Tags: ftp, remote-access

I am able to connect to my FTP host properly, but whenever I upload any file I get some error.

Here are some examples:

[image: screencap1]

[image: screencap2]

Why can't I upload files?

Comment: Your FTP user has inadequate writing permissions in the destination directory. Use another user, extend the permissions, or add your user to another user group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the folder properties on the `FTP Host` you need to give permission to the user you're logging in as.

The simplest way of giving permissions to the user is through the `Advanced Sharing` option on the `Sharing` tab in the folders properties.